# Skipping some y values in ceiling graph

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to plot a graph of `ceil(3^x)` for the domain `0:4`. I can get the graph just fine. However, compared to the x values, the y range is very large and the jump marks are nearly tiny at higher values of y. So what I would like to achieve is keep the domain as it is i.e., `0:4`, but for y values, we can start from 0 to 5, and then 79 to 81. It is to be noted that the jump marks are labelled in terms of logarithmic values of x which I am able to do so manually. Also, I would like to show the dotted part of y-axis, indicating that some y values have been skipped. I could omit y tick marks by mentioning them explicitly such as `ytick={0,1,2,3,4,5,79,80,81}`, however, It does not skip the graph for all the excluded values of y for the given range.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        set layers,
        axis lines=middle,
        xmin=-0.1,
        xmax=4.5,
        ymin=-2,
        ymax=84.5,
        ytick={0,1,2,3,4,5,79,80,81},
        enlarge y limits=false,
        extra x ticks={0},
        extra y ticks={0},
        xlabel={$x$},
        ylabel={$y$},
            every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=north west},
                every axis y label/.style={at={(current axis.above origin)},anchor=east},
        grid,
        grid style=dashed,
        ticklabel style={fill=white,fill opacity=0.7,text opacity=1},
    ]
        \addplot[thick,red,jump mark mid,samples=1000,domain=0:4]{ceil(3^x)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**UPDATE**

This one's close to what I want to achieve, thanks to
hpekristiansen's original answer.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-0.1,
    xmax=4.5,
}
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$},
    ymin=-0.2,
    ymax=10, restrict y to domain=0:5,
    ytick={0,1,2,3,4,5}
]
    \addplot[thick,red,jump mark mid,samples=1000,domain=0:4]{ceil(3^x)};
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[
    axis x line=none,
    restrict y to domain=78:81,
    ymin=71,
    ymax=82,
    ytick={79,80,81},
]
    \addplot[thick,red,jump mark mid,samples=1000,domain=0:4]{ceil(3^x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{
axis lines=middle,
xmin=-0.1, xmax=4.5,
y axis line style={draw=none},
}

\begin{axis}[
xlabel={$x$},
ylabel={$y$},
ymin=0, ymax=10, restrict y to domain=0:5,
ytick={0,1,2,3,4,5},
]
\addplot[thick,red,jump mark mid,samples=1000,domain=0:4]{ceil(3^x)};
%manual y-axis
\draw (0,0) -- (0,5.5); \draw[dotted] (0,5.5) -- (0,7); \draw[-stealth] (0,7) -- (0,10);
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[
axis x line=none,
ymin=71, ymax=82, restrict y to domain=79:81,
ytick={79,80,81},
]
\addplot[thick,red,jump mark mid,samples=1000,domain=0:4]{ceil(3^x)};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with break in y-axis]

Comment: I actually want the y-values including 79,80,81 to be on the same y-axis. could it be possible to make some part of y axis dotted to show y-values above 5 and below 79 are skipped?

Comment: Yes - I can do that. Please first answer, if you are happy with the graph(the red part) itself!? For me it looks horribel and not easier to understand than the full graph.

Comment: Yeah I know the graph's horrible, however that's because I want some space to label the between jump marks. It's harder to do so with full graph.

Comment: Have a look at my edit, and see if this is what you are after!?